# How to Implement and Check DKIM in Salesfroce

Tags: salesforce, dkim, salesforce-service-cloud

Could you guys explain to me that how to implement and check DKIM in Salesforce with example

Thanks in Advance,
Vingesh.B

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to do this, you have to be a System Administrator in Salesforce and have the ability to modify your DNS records with your domain registrar.
The process involves creating a unique key in Salesforce, then create the DNS record that uses the key.

[Create a DKIM Key in Salesforce Classic](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=emailadmin_create_dkim_key.htm&type=0)